# Let keyword not showing the global value after the block scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am learning ES6 and in https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_let.asp
i saw an example:

```
let i = 5;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // some statements
}
// Here i is 5
```

So, I tried in my own way:

```js
 
const name='ashwin';
let message='suju';
     
for(const i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   message = `${i} count now`;
   console.log(message);
}

console.log(message+'aa');
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

My expected output at this point `console.log(message+'aa');`was
 : `sujuaa` but I am seeing `'9 count nowaa'`.Since, after the block scope, in let keyword, it accesses the value as defined for global scope. It has been also shown for example in w3schools. Can someone clarify to me , why after finishing the block scope, I am not getting the value of global scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the message in global scope - the problem is, you're also modifying that message within the loop. To make a loop that modifies a block-scoped variable, redefine it with `let` in the loop:

```js
let name = 'ashwin';
let message = 'suju';

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let message = `${i} count now`;
  console.log(message);
}
console.log(message + 'aa');
```

In your example, you're modifying `message` within the loop, not copying it, so you're going to be modifying the global variable. Just using `let` doesn't restrict it to within blocks and automatically make copies - in your case it simply prevents it from being declared twice as you're using it in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let name='ashwin';
let message='suju';
   
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  let message=`${i} count now`; // In your example from w3schools he used let 2x first in defining in the global scope and let for defining the variable. In your example you only used let one time in the global scope, defining it again in the local scope will give you your desired output.
  console.log(message);
}
console.log(message + 'aa');
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so,if i dont declare it like this   let message=`${i} count now`;  ,then the block scope of let statement also fails?